# How to disable the cache while making a REST API call from SOAP UI?

Tags: rest, caching, soapui

How to disable the cache in a rest test request in a test step in SOAP UI, anything like `setUseCaches(false)` as in URLConnection class.

Whenever, the API is triggered in short duration the response is not changing, because of the cache.

- tried with below steps:

  1. setting the Cache Definition to false in project properties
  2. setting system property soapui.http.custom.headers.cache=false

Any suggestion will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are confused. SoapUI caches only the request parameters. The response caching is a feature of the API server.

Comment: In java or grovvy for making a rest request:

URLConnection urlConnection = new URL("http://example.com").openConnection();
urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);

In this case I can tell not use to caches. Is there anything similar in Soap UI saying for any Rest Request made don't use cache.